# Using Docker to run a laravel app, I am getting content load from http, and not https

Tags: nginx, docker

I am dockerizing my laravel app, and when it loads, I get an error saying that mixed content cant be served. I look at source code of html page, and it does load the app.js file from http scheme, despite me being on https. When I install the same laravel app on my own nginx server with redirection to https, the app.js is rendered with https. So its not a thing with laravel. How do I make nginx conf inside Docker serve content to https? My current .conf file is this:

```
server {
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Comment: You likely need to tell Laravel to trust the traffic coming from the Docker network. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies Try trusting `*`, and then narrow it down if that helps.

Comment: i want to configure this on nginx, as i am making a service, where people can upload their own laravel apps, and i dont want to make them add or change their source code

Comment: The Laravel app is where the URL generation occurs, and Laravel has a built-in and documented way of handling proxies like nginx, Docker, load balancers, etc. That's where the solution lies.